# Skip comments & surroundingSpacesNeedQuotes with supercsv 2.2.0

Tags: supercsv

I would ignore comments start with '#' char and surrounding spaces with quotes but with opencsv 2.2.0 does not work.
I searched into the source of supercsv but the skip comment feature preference it never used into the code.
Can you help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/preferences.html#Skipping_comments) on the website demonstrates, you have to create a custom `CsvPreference` and pass that to your CsvReader's constructor. e.g.

```
// create the custom preference
CsvPreference skipCommentsPreference = new CsvPreference.Builder(
    CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE)
   .skipComments(new CommentStartsWith("#").build();

// create your reader with the preference
ICsvBeanReader beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(
    new FileReader("my.csv"), skipCommentsPreference);
```